how to post data in node.js with content type ='application/x-www-form-urlencoded' with package https
how can the package "https" be used to send a POST Call but with urlencoded body? I can't use any package other than https
"data" needs to be URL encoded, since the target Endpoint expects it
const options = {
  agent,
  hostname: "myTestURL.com",
  port: 443,
  path: '/foo',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
}
    
let response = ''
const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
  res.on('data', (d) => {
    response += d
  })
})
    
req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(e)
})
    
req.write(new URLSearchParams(data))
req.end()


Simply format your data as URL-encoded and include it in the request body

Which means objects like this
{ key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
should be converted to 'key1=value1&key2=value2'

Then setup the request object like this
{
hostname: 'example.com',
path: '/path/to/resource',
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
}


That should do it!
